# Variable declaration of same data type in a single line

Tags: powershell, variables

A simple problem but been having trouble getting around it. So I have this code:

```
$ListBoxData = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$ListBoxLog= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$ListBoxError= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
```

How can I rewrite this a little cleaner by having them in a single line, since they are all of same data types. Something like below:

```
$ListBoxData, $ListBoxLog, $ListBoxError = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
```

or

```
New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox (@($ListBoxData, $ListBoxLog, $ListBoxError))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the numbers in a foreach-object construct like so:

```
'error','log','whateveryouwant' | 
 % { New-Variable -Name listbox$_ -Value (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox) -Force }
```

Comment: Well, One issue though, I dont plan to name them Listbox1, listbox2 in that order. Each will have a relevant name to its working mode

Comment: the concept remains the same...you need to replace the digits with your relevant names. anyway see updated answer..

Comment: Thanks Kiran. That's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Another way (using the [range operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx)):

```
$ListBoxData, $ListBoxLog, $ListBoxError = 1..3 | % { New-Object Windows.Forms.ListBox }
```